# Opennms how to poll services that are listed as Not Monitored?

Tags: opennms

I'm runninng Opennms in a Docker.io container: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/study/opennms/

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 -d postgres
```

and

```
$ docker run --name some-opennms --link some-postgres:postgres -p 8980:8980 -d 'study/opennms'
```

Works like a charm. user/pwd: admin/admin as default login.

I've added a custom http detector through Home > Admin > Provisioning Requisitions > Edit Foreign Source Definition. The detector basically checks the 8111 for a HTTP 200 response, named it *teamcity* as it's meant to detect Teamcity running.

Added a node through Home > Admin > Add Interface which appears on the Home > Search > Node List screen.

Now the problem I have is: in the availability window the custom service shows as "Not monitored". Looked around on the interwebs, found this: http://www.opennms.org/wiki/FAQ-Configuration#Q:_Why_are_some_services_listed_as_Not_Monitored.3F

Logged into the container:

```
$ docker exec -it opennms bash
```

Checked the config file: */etc/opennms/poller-configuration.xml*. File is just the default configuration, doesn't show any custom added servcices. So I search the filesystem

```
$ cat /etc/opennms/*.xml | grep *teamcity*
```

It finds the detector /etc/opennms/default-foreign-source.xml. But that file doesn't contain the service definition which includes the option to switch the service detection on, it just contains the detectors.

How do I get the availability of the service to show as "monitored"? Can I configure the poller to check the availability of a service from the admin UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable polling (and thus monitor the service state) you actually have to [edit the poller-configuration.xml](https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-admin/guide-admin.html#ga-pollerd-configuration) and add an entry for the service you want to poll. I was pretty amazed to find that Opennms does not supply a UI for this rather crucial use case.